# How to copy/inherit all the namespaces from the source xml into the stylesheet?

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

I have input xml file with multiple namespaces declared in it. In order the stylesheet can process elements with prefixes, I need to manually copy the namespace declarations form the input xml to stylesheet.

My question is: Is there more elegant way to let the stylesheet know the namespaces form the input xml? In other words to inherit those namespace declarations from the input xml.

**EDIT 1**
The input xml named **content.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<office:document-content xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0" xmlns:anim="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:animation:1.0" xmlns:chart="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:chart:1.0" xmlns:config="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:config:1.0" xmlns:db="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:database:1.0" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dr3d="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:dr3d:1.0" xmlns:draw="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:drawing:1.0" xmlns:fo="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0" xmlns:form="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:form:1.0" xmlns:grddl="http://www.w3.org/2003/g/data-view#" xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:meta="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0" xmlns:number="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:datastyle:1.0" xmlns:presentation="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:presentation:1.0" xmlns:script="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:script:1.0" xmlns:smil="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:smil-compatible:1.0" xmlns:style="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0" xmlns:svg="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:svg-compatible:1.0" xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0" xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0" xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" office:version="1.2">
    <office:font-face-decls>
        <style:font-face style:name="Liberation Serif" svg:font-family="Liberation Serif" style:font-family-generic="roman" style:font-pitch="variable" svg:panose-1="2 2 6 3 5 4 5 2 3 4"/>
        <style:font-face style:name="SimSun" svg:font-family="SimSun" style:font-family-generic="system" style:font-pitch="variable" svg:panose-1="2 1 6 0 3 1 1 1 1 1"/>
        <style:font-face style:name="Mangal" svg:font-family="Mangal" style:font-family-generic="roman" style:font-pitch="variable" svg:panose-1="2 4 5 3 5 2 3 3 2 2"/>
        <style:font-face style:name="Calibri Light" svg:font-family="Calibri Light" style:font-family-generic="swiss" style:font-pitch="variable" svg:panose-1="2 15 3 2 2 2 4 3 2 4"/>
        <style:font-face style:name="F" svg:font-family="F" style:font-family-generic="system" style:font-pitch="variable"/>
        <style:font-face style:name="Liberation Sans" svg:font-family="Liberation Sans" style:font-family-generic="swiss" style:font-pitch="variable" svg:panose-1="2 11 6 4 2 2 2 2 2 4"/>
        <style:font-face style:name="Microsoft YaHei" svg:font-family="Microsoft YaHei" style:font-family-generic="swiss" style:font-pitch="variable" svg:panose-1="2 11 5 3 2 2 4 2 2 4"/>
        <style:font-face style:name="Times New Roman" svg:font-family="Times New Roman" style:font-family-generic="roman" style:font-pitch="variable" svg:panose-1="2 2 6 3 5 4 5 2 3 4"/>
        <style:font-face style:name="DeusEx" svg:font-family="DeusEx" style:font-family-generic="roman" style:font-pitch="variable"/>
        <style:font-face style:name="Cambria" svg:font-family="Cambria" style:font-family-generic="roman" style:font-pitch="variable" svg:panose-1="2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4"/>
        <style:font-face style:name="Arial" svg:font-family="Arial" style:font-family-generic="swiss" style:font-pitch="variable" svg:panose-1="2 11 6 4 2 2 2 2 2 4"/>
        <style:font-face style:name="Calibri" svg:font-family="Calibri" style:font-family-generic="swiss" style:font-pitch="variable" svg:panose-1="2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4"/>
    </office:font-face-decls>
    <office:automatic-styles>
        <style:style style:name="P1" style:parent-style-name="Style2" style:master-page-name="MP0" style:family="paragraph">
            <style:paragraph-properties fo:break-before="page" fo:margin-top="0in" fo:margin-bottom="0in"/>
        </style:style>
        <style:style style:name="T2" style:parent-style-name="DefaultParagraphFont" style:family="text">
            <style:text-properties style:font-name="Cambria" style:font-name-complex="Arial" fo:color="#000000"/>
        </style:style>
        <style:style style:name="T3" style:parent-style-name="DefaultParagraphFont" style:family="text">
            <style:text-properties style:font-name="Cambria" style:font-name-complex="Arial" fo:color="#000000" fo:language="en" fo:country="US"/>
        </style:style>
        <style:style style:name="T4" style:parent-style-name="DefaultParagraphFont" style:family="text">
            <style:text-properties style:font-name="Cambria" style:font-name-complex="Arial" fo:color="#000000"/>
        </style:style>
        <style:style style:name="T5" style:parent-style-name="DefaultParagraphFont" style:family="text">
            <style:text-properties style:font-name="Cambria" style:font-name-complex="Arial" fo:color="#000000" fo:language="en" fo:country="US"/>
        </style:style>
        <style:style style:name="T6" style:parent-style-name="DefaultParagraphFont" style:family="text">
            <style:text-properties style:font-name="Cambria" style:font-name-complex="Arial" fo:color="#000000"/>
        </style:style>
        <style:style style:name="T7" style:parent-style-name="DefaultParagraphFont" style:family="text">
            <style:text-properties style:font-name="Cambria" style:font-name-complex="Arial" fo:color="#000000" fo:language="en" fo:country="US"/>
        </style:style>
        <style:style style:name="T8" style:parent-style-name="DefaultParagraphFont" style:family="text">
            <style:text-properties style:font-name="Cambria" style:font-name-complex="Arial" fo:color="#000000"/>
        </style:style>
        <style:style style:name="T9" style:parent-style-name="BoldStyle" style:family="text">
            <style:text-properties style:font-name="Cambria" style:font-name-complex="Arial" fo:color="#000000"/>
        </style:style>
        <style:style style:name="T10" style:parent-style-name="DefaultParagraphFont" style:family="text">
            <style:text-properties style:font-name="Cambria" style:font-name-complex="Arial" fo:color="#000000"/>
        </style:style>
        <style:style style:name="T11" style:parent-style-name="DefaultParagraphFont" style:family="text">
            <style:text-properties style:language-asian="bg" style:country-asian="BG" style:language-complex="ar" style:country-complex="SA"/>
        </style:style>
        <style:style style:name="T12" style:parent-style-name="DefaultParagraphFont" style:family="text">
            <style:text-properties style:font-name="Cambria" style:font-name-complex="Arial" fo:color="#000000"/>
        </style:style>
        <style:style style:name="T13" style:parent-style-name="DefaultParagraphFont" style:family="text">
            <style:text-properties style:font-name="Cambria" style:font-name-complex="Arial" fo:color="#000000" fo:language="en" fo:country="US"/>
        </style:style>
        <style:style style:name="T14" style:parent-style-name="DefaultParagraphFont" style:family="text">
            <style:text-properties style:font-name="Cambria" style:font-name-complex="Arial" fo:color="#000000"/>
        </style:style>
        <style:style style:name="T15" style:parent-style-name="DefaultParagraphFont" style:family="text">
            <style:text-properties style:font-name="Cambria" style:font-name-complex="Arial" fo:color="#000000" fo:language="en" fo:country="US"/>
        </style:style>
        <style:style style:name="T16" style:parent-style-name="DefaultParagraphFont" style:family="text">
            <style:text-properties style:font-name="Cambria" style:font-name-complex="Arial" fo:color="#000000"/>
        </style:style>
        <style:style style:family="graphic" style:name="a0" style:parent-style-name="Graphics">
            <style:graphic-properties fo:border="0.01042in none" fo:background-color="transparent" fo:clip="rect(0in, 0in, 0in, 0in)"/>
        </style:style>
    </office:automatic-styles>
    <office:body>
        <office:text text:use-soft-page-breaks="true">
            <text:p text:style-name="P1"/>
            <text:p text:style-name="Title">
                <text:span text:style-name="T2">Запознаване със<text:s/></text:span>
                <text:span text:style-name="T3">JTAG<text:s/></text:span>
                <text:span text:style-name="T4">протокол за програмиране на<text:s/></text:span>
                <text:span text:style-name="T5">MSP430</text:span>
                <text:span text:style-name="T6">Запознаване с функционалността на<text:s/></text:span>
                <text:span text:style-name="T7">Real Time Clock.</text:span>
            </text:p>
            <text:p text:style-name="Standard"/>
            <text:p text:style-name="Subtitle">
                <text:span text:style-name="T8">Създаване на<text:s/></text:span>
                <text:span text:style-name="T9">часовник</text:span>
                <text:span text:style-name="T10"><text:s/>с календар в реално време.</text:span>
            </text:p>
            <text:p text:style-name="Standard">
                <text:span text:style-name="T11">
                    <draw:frame draw:style-name="a0" draw:name="Picture 1" text:anchor-type="as-char" svg:x="0in" svg:y="0in" svg:width="6.6875in" svg:height="3.11458in" style:rel-width="scale" style:rel-height="scale">
                        <draw:image xlink:href="media/image1.png" xlink:type="simple" xlink:show="embed" xlink:actuate="onLoad"/>
                        <svg:title/>
                        <svg:desc/>
                    </draw:frame>
                </text:span>
            </text:p>
            <text:h text:style-name="Heading1" text:outline-level="1">
                <text:span text:style-name="T12">Запознаване с<text:s/></text:span>
                <text:span text:style-name="T13">UART<text:s/></text:span>
                <text:span text:style-name="T14">периферията на</text:span>
                <text:span text:style-name="T15"><text:s/>MSP430F5438.</text:span>
            </text:h>
            <text:p text:style-name="Standard"/>
            <text:h text:style-name="Heading2" text:outline-level="2">
                <text:span text:style-name="T16">Създаване на график за аларма и реализиране на прекъсвания по зададени час и дата.</text:span>
            </text:h>
        </office:text>
    </office:body>
</office:document-content>
```

The stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

<office:document-content xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0" xmlns:anim="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:animation:1.0" xmlns:chart="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:chart:1.0" xmlns:config="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:config:1.0" xmlns:db="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:database:1.0" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dr3d="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:dr3d:1.0" xmlns:draw="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:drawing:1.0" xmlns:fo="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0" xmlns:form="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:form:1.0" xmlns:grddl="http://www.w3.org/2003/g/data-view#" xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:meta="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0" xmlns:number="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:datastyle:1.0" xmlns:presentation="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:presentation:1.0" xmlns:script="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:script:1.0" xmlns:smil="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:smil-compatible:1.0" xmlns:style="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0" xmlns:svg="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:svg-compatible:1.0" xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0" xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0" xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" office:version="1.2">
    <office:font-face-decls>
        <style:font-face style:name="Liberation Serif" svg:font-family="Liberation Serif" style:font-family-generic="roman" style:font-pitch="variable" svg:panose-1="2 2 6 3 5 4 5 2 3 4"/>
        <style:font-face style:name="SimSun" svg:font-family="SimSun" style:font-family-generic="system" style:font-pitch="variable" svg:panose-1="2 1 6 0 3 1 1 1 1 1"/>
        <style:font-face style:name="Mangal" svg:font-family="Mangal" style:font-family-generic="roman" style:font-pitch="variable" svg:panose-1="2 4 5 3 5 2 3 3 2 2"/>
        <style:font-face style:name="Calibri Light" svg:font-family="Calibri Light" style:font-family-generic="swiss" style:font-pitch="variable" svg:panose-1="2 15 3 2 2 2 4 3 2 4"/>
        <style:font-face style:name="F" svg:font-family="F" style:font-family-generic="system" style:font-pitch="variable"/>
        <style:font-face style:name="Liberation Sans" svg:font-family="Liberation Sans" style:font-family-generic="swiss" style:font-pitch="variable" svg:panose-1="2 11 6 4 2 2 2 2 2 4"/>
        <style:font-face style:name="Microsoft YaHei" svg:font-family="Microsoft YaHei" style:font-family-generic="swiss" style:font-pitch="variable" svg:panose-1="2 11 5 3 2 2 4 2 2 4"/>
        <style:font-face style:name="Times New Roman" svg:font-family="Times New Roman" style:font-family-generic="roman" style:font-pitch="variable" svg:panose-1="2 2 6 3 5 4 5 2 3 4"/>
        <style:font-face style:name="DeusEx" svg:font-family="DeusEx" style:font-family-generic="roman" style:font-pitch="variable"/>
        <style:font-face style:name="Cambria" svg:font-family="Cambria" style:font-family-generic="roman" style:font-pitch="variable" svg:panose-1="2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4"/>
        <style:font-face style:name="Arial" svg:font-family="Arial" style:font-family-generic="swiss" style:font-pitch="variable" svg:panose-1="2 11 6 4 2 2 2 2 2 4"/>
        <style:font-face style:name="Calibri" svg:font-family="Calibri" style:font-family-generic="swiss" style:font-pitch="variable" svg:panose-1="2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4"/>
    </office:font-face-decls>
    <office:automatic-styles>
        <style:style style:name="P1" style:parent-style-name="Style2" style:master-page-name="MP0" style:family="paragraph">
            <style:paragraph-properties fo:break-before="page" fo:margin-top="0in" fo:margin-bottom="0in"/>
        </style:style>
        <style:style style:name="T2" style:parent-style-name="DefaultParagraphFont" style:family="text">
            <style:text-properties style:font-name="Cambria" style:font-name-complex="Arial" fo:color="#000000"/>
        </style:style>
        <style:style style:name="T3" style:parent-style-name="DefaultParagraphFont" style:family="text">
            <style:text-properties style:font-name="Cambria" style:font-name-complex="Arial" fo:color="#000000" fo:language="en" fo:country="US"/>
        </style:style>
        <style:style style:name="T4" style:parent-style-name="DefaultParagraphFont" style:family="text">
            <style:text-properties style:font-name="Cambria" style:font-name-complex="Arial" fo:color="#000000"/>
        </style:style>
        <style:style style:name="T5" style:parent-style-name="DefaultParagraphFont" style:family="text">
            <style:text-properties style:font-name="Cambria" style:font-name-complex="Arial" fo:color="#000000" fo:language="en" fo:country="US"/>
        </style:style>
        <style:style style:name="T6" style:parent-style-name="DefaultParagraphFont" style:family="text">
            <style:text-properties style:font-name="Cambria" style:font-name-complex="Arial" fo:color="#000000"/>
        </style:style>
        <style:style style:name="T7" style:parent-style-name="DefaultParagraphFont" style:family="text">
            <style:text-properties style:font-name="Cambria" style:font-name-complex="Arial" fo:color="#000000" fo:language="en" fo:country="US"/>
        </style:style>
        <style:style style:name="T8" style:parent-style-name="DefaultParagraphFont" style:family="text">
            <style:text-properties style:font-name="Cambria" style:font-name-complex="Arial" fo:color="#000000"/>
        </style:style>
        <style:style style:name="T9" style:parent-style-name="BoldStyle" style:family="text">
            <style:text-properties style:font-name="Cambria" style:font-name-complex="Arial" fo:color="#000000"/>
        </style:style>
        <style:style style:name="T10" style:parent-style-name="DefaultParagraphFont" style:family="text">
            <style:text-properties style:font-name="Cambria" style:font-name-complex="Arial" fo:color="#000000"/>
        </style:style>
        <style:style style:name="T11" style:parent-style-name="DefaultParagraphFont" style:family="text">
            <style:text-properties style:language-asian="bg" style:country-asian="BG" style:language-complex="ar" style:country-complex="SA"/>
        </style:style>
        <style:style style:name="T12" style:parent-style-name="DefaultParagraphFont" style:family="text">
            <style:text-properties style:font-name="Cambria" style:font-name-complex="Arial" fo:color="#000000"/>
        </style:style>
        <style:style style:name="T13" style:parent-style-name="DefaultParagraphFont" style:family="text">
            <style:text-properties style:font-name="Cambria" style:font-name-complex="Arial" fo:color="#000000" fo:language="en" fo:country="US"/>
        </style:style>
        <style:style style:name="T14" style:parent-style-name="DefaultParagraphFont" style:family="text">
            <style:text-properties style:font-name="Cambria" style:font-name-complex="Arial" fo:color="#000000"/>
        </style:style>
        <style:style style:name="T15" style:parent-style-name="DefaultParagraphFont" style:family="text">
            <style:text-properties style:font-name="Cambria" style:font-name-complex="Arial" fo:color="#000000" fo:language="en" fo:country="US"/>
        </style:style>
        <style:style style:name="T16" style:parent-style-name="DefaultParagraphFont" style:family="text">
            <style:text-properties style:font-name="Cambria" style:font-name-complex="Arial" fo:color="#000000"/>
        </style:style>
        <style:style style:family="graphic" style:name="a0" style:parent-style-name="Graphics">
            <style:graphic-properties fo:border="0.01042in none" fo:background-color="transparent" fo:clip="rect(0in, 0in, 0in, 0in)"/>
        </style:style>
    </office:automatic-styles>
    <office:body>
        <office:text text:use-soft-page-breaks="true">
            <text:p text:style-name="P1"/>
            <text:p text:style-name="Title">
                <text:span text:style-name="T2">Запознаване със<text:s/></text:span>
                <text:span text:style-name="T3">JTAG<text:s/></text:span>
                <text:span text:style-name="T4">протокол за програмиране на<text:s/></text:span>
                <text:span text:style-name="T5">MSP430</text:span>
                <text:span text:style-name="T6">Запознаване с функционалността на<text:s/></text:span>
                <text:span text:style-name="T7">Real Time Clock.</text:span>
            </text:p>
            <text:p text:style-name="Standard"/>
            <text:p text:style-name="Subtitle">
                <text:span text:style-name="T8">Създаване на<text:s/></text:span>
                <text:span text:style-name="T9">часовник</text:span>
                <text:span text:style-name="T10"><text:s/>с календар в реално време.</text:span>
            </text:p>
            <text:p text:style-name="Standard">
                <text:span text:style-name="T11">
                    <draw:frame draw:style-name="a0" draw:name="Picture 1" text:anchor-type="as-char" svg:x="0in" svg:y="0in" svg:width="6.6875in" svg:height="3.11458in" style:rel-width="scale" style:rel-height="scale">
                        <draw:image xlink:href="media/image1.png" xlink:type="simple" xlink:show="embed" xlink:actuate="onLoad"/>
                        <svg:title/>
                        <svg:desc/>
                    </draw:frame>
                </text:span>
            </text:p>
            <text:h text:style-name="Heading1" text:outline-level="1">
                <text:span text:style-name="T12">Запознаване с<text:s/></text:span>
                <text:span text:style-name="T13">UART<text:s/></text:span>
                <text:span text:style-name="T14">периферията на</text:span>
                <text:span text:style-name="T15"><text:s/>MSP430F5438.</text:span>
            </text:h>
            <text:p text:style-name="Standard"/>
            <text:h text:style-name="Heading2" text:outline-level="2">
                <text:span text:style-name="T16">Създаване на график за аларма и реализиране на прекъсвания по зададени час и дата.</text:span>
            </text:h>
        </office:text>
    </office:body>
</office:document-content>
```

The result I want is achieved. The output is not the problem. The problem is that each input file may consist of different namespace declarations, therefore for each new input xml I need to process I have to manually copy the namespace declarations form the xml file to the xsl file.

Until now I had typed the namespace declarations manually. But they tend to become more and more.

Please excuse my poor English!

Comment: Please show the a relevant input sample and the relevant result sample, together with the XSLT you have. For instance, if you copy an element with e.g. `<xsl:template match="foo"><xsl:copy>...</xsl:copy></xsl:template>`, the in-scope namespaces are copied. You can also copy namespace nodes  using `<xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>`, where you need or want to do that depends on the input XML and the output you want.

Comment: @Martin Honnen , The output is not the target of this question. I don't even want those declarations into my output. What bothers me is that, this stylesheet  has to be designed to process different xml files with common structure. Each of those xml files, contains different namespace declarations. Therefore for each new xml that is to be processed, the stylesheet has to be updated/edited with the corresponding namespace declarations from the input xml.

Comment: So you have different but similar input formats which only differ in namespaces? Well XSLT/XPath 2.0 allows you to use `*:foo` to select or match `foo` elements in any namespace. XSLT can also generate XSLT,  if you need to process the namespaces in an XML input and generate XSLT using those namespaces.

Comment: They would differ in namespaces if there is a tag or attribute that belongs to a different URI. I don't know yet the entire count of the namespaces it may hold, but whenever I change something into the `.odt` document, new namespaces appear. Anyway, you helped me a a lot thank you @Martin Honnen.